# To connect eclipse with database

Tags: java, selenium, jdbc

I have written a code to connect eclipse with sql server to automate database.

I have tried writing the code with help of various sites but in vain.

Here is the code I have written:

```
import java.sql.*;  

class mysqlcon{  

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
     Connection con = null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     ResultSet rs = null;

     String host= "localhost";
     String user = "shamima";
     String passwd = "Welcome@123"; 


        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
             con=DriverManager.getConnection(  

                   "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/eatngo",user,passwd);  

             stmt=con.createStatement();  
             rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from 
                           ezee_posguest_master");  
            while(rs.next())  
                System.out.println("connection 
                                                 established");  
        con.close();  
        }catch(Exception e)
        { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }         
    }
```

I simply want to connect my eclipse with database thats all.

But I get an error as:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Unknown initial character set index '255' received from server. Initial client character set can be forced via the 'characterEncoding' property."

Answer (score 0):

Character Set Support UTF-8 It works for me.

> url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?characterEncoding=utf-8&useConfigs=maxPerformance